# V12.1 shows extra space using BarChart3D compared to V12

Tags: labeling, charts, version-12.1

V 12.1 on windows 10 shows extra space above and below `BarChart3D` compared to V 12 using the same code.

I'like to put a label above this one below, but the space always where the bars stop and the label is too large using V 12.1. This does not happen in V12. All on same PC.

I tried different ways to put the label, and still the empty space does not shrink. I tried `Labeled` also and `Grid`. Also tried adding `ImageMargins -> 0, ImagePadding -> 0` as option to the `BarChart3D` command, but that had no effect on reducing the white space above and below.

Here is the one I am using now.

```
dataForChart = {{0.8, 0, 0, 99.2}, {14.285, 0, 0, 100}, 
   {28.571, 0, 14.285, 57.1428}, {0, 0, 0, 100}, {28.571,0, 14.2857, 57.142857}, 
   {28.5714,0, 0, 71.42857}, {57.14285, 0, 14.28571, 28.57142}};

casNames = {
   Text@Style["Rubi", Bold, 10],
   Text@Style["Mathematica", Bold, 10],
   Text@Style["Maple", Bold, 10],
   Text@Style["FriCAS", Bold, 10],
   Text@Style["Giac/Xcas", Bold, 10],
   Text@Style["Sympy", Bold, 10],
   Text@Style["Maxima", Bold, 10]
   };

percentageSolvedByRubi = 99.2;
percentageSolvedByM = 85.714;
percentageSolvedByMaple = 71.4286;
percentageSolvedByFricas = 100.;
percentageSolvedByGiac = 71.4286;
percentageSolvedBySympy = 71.4286;
percentageSolvedByMaxima = 42.8571;

Grid[
 {
  {Text[Style["Antiderivative Grade distribution for each CAS", 20]]},
  {Text[Style[
     "Numbers shown on bars are total percentage solved for each CAS",
      10]]},
  {
   BarChart3D[
    dataForChart,
    ChartLayout -> "Percentile",
    ChartStyle -> { Red,   
      RGBColor[255/255, 255/255, 0/255], 
      RGBColor[51/255, 51/255, 255/255], 
      RGBColor[50/255, 205/255, 50/255]},
    ChartLabels -> {Placed[casNames, Below ], None},
    ImageSize -> 500,
    FaceGrids -> None,
    Axes -> False,
    ChartBaseStyle -> EdgeForm[None],
    ImageSize -> 400,
    PlotRange -> {0, 110},
    BarSpacing -> 1.4, PlotTheme -> "Classic", Background -> None, 
    Lighting -> None, Method -> {"Canvas" -> None},
    ChartLegends -> {"F", "C", "B", "A"},
    Epilog -> {(*same order as names listed above*)
       Text[
       Style[ToString[Round[percentageSolvedByRubi, 0.01]] <> "%", 
        Bold], Scaled[{.14, .6}]],
      Text[
       Style[ToString[Round[percentageSolvedByM, 0.01]] <> "%", Bold],
        Scaled[{.25, .6}]],
      Text[
       Style[ToString[Round[percentageSolvedByMaple, 0.01]] <> "%", 
        Bold], Scaled[{.37, .6}]],
      Text[
       Style[ToString[Round[percentageSolvedByFricas, 0.01]] <> "%", 
        Bold], Scaled[{.48, .6}]],
      Text[
       Style[ToString[Round[percentageSolvedByGiac, 0.01]] <> "%", 
        Bold], Scaled[{.61, .6}]],
      Text[
       Style[ToString[Round[percentageSolvedBySympy, 0.01]] <> "%", 
        Bold], Scaled[{.72, .6}]],
      Text[
       Style[ToString[Round[percentageSolvedByMaxima, 0.01]] <> "%", 
        Bold], Scaled[{.84, .6}]]
      }
    ]
   }
  }, Frame -> All, Spacings -> {1, 0}]
```

Running the above gives

[image]

Any suggestions what to do?

Thanks to comment by Kglr, I tried this on the cloud. The space is indeed gone, but the numbers on the bar charts are now shifted when compared to how they look in the notebook. This is all too strange.

[image]

**Update:**

I just found that this could be a bug!  I tried the same code on V 12 on the same PC, and this is the output

[image]

Is this a bug??

Comment: probably os-related. No extra space on Wolfram Cloud.

Comment: @kglr I think this a bug now !  I just tried the same code on V12 on same PC and it gives correct output. No extra space.

Comment: can you try if changing the `Method` option to  `Method -> {"Canvas" -> None, "ShrinkWrap" -> True}` helps?

Comment: @kglr thanks for the suggestion. I just did. No effect.

Comment: any reason for `BarChart3D` instead of `BarChart`?

Comment: @kglr I liked the 3D look more for this type of chart that is all. Makes it a little more cool looking I suppose. I could always just use V 12 for now to process this, since V 12 has no extra space there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get the 3D look with `BarChart` using `ChartElementFunction -> "ObliqueRectangle"`.

```
percentSolved = PercentForm /@ 
   ({42.857, 85.714, 71.4286, 100., 71.4286, 71.4286, 42.8571}/100); 

bc = BarChart[MapThread[Labeled, {dataForChart, casNames}], 
   ChartLayout -> "Percentile", 
   ChartStyle -> {Red, RGBColor[255/255, 255/255, 0/255], 
       RGBColor[51/255, 51/255, 255/255], 
       RGBColor[50/255, 205/255, 50/255]}, 
   ChartElementFunction -> "ObliqueRectangle",
   ChartLabels -> {Placed[percentSolved, {{.5, 1}, {.5, 5}}], None},
   ImageSize -> 500, Axes -> {True, False},
   AxesStyle -> Directive["LineColor" -> None],
   ChartBaseStyle -> EdgeForm[None],
   BarSpacing -> .4, PlotTheme -> "Classic",
   ChartLegends -> {"F", "C", "B", "A"}]
```

[image]

```
Grid[{{Text[Style["Antiderivative Grade distribution for each CAS", 20]]},
  {Text[Style["Numbers shown on bars are total percentage solved for each  CAS", 10]]}, 
  {bc}}, 
  Frame -> All, Spacings -> {1, 1}]
```

[image]

```
 $Version
```

> ```
> "12.1.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (March 4, 2020)" (* Wolfram Cloud *)
> ```

In version 11.3.0 (Windows 10) change the definition of `percentSolved` to

```
percentSolved = Row[{Round[#, .01], "%"}] & /@
  {42.857, 85.714, 71.4286, 100., 71.4286, 71.4286, 42.8571};
```

to get

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Both methods used v. 12.1 on a Mac.

**Method 1**

You can get a slight improvement by adjusting the `AspectRatio`.
For example, with `AspectRatio->0.7`, some space is removed.
It also reduces the heights of the bars.

[image: barchart 3D]

---

**Method 2**: Rasterize the bar chart

```
barchart = BarChart3D[dataForChart,ImageSize -> 700,ChartLayout -> "Percentile", ChartStyle -> {Red, RGBColor[255/255, 255/255, 0/255], RGBColor[51/255, 51/255, 255/255], RGBColor[50/255, 205/255, 50/255]}, ChartLabels -> {Placed[casNames, Below], None}, FaceGrids -> None, Axes -> False, ChartBaseStyle -> EdgeForm[None], PlotRange -> {0, 110}, BarSpacing -> 1.4, PlotTheme -> "Classic", Background -> None, Lighting -> None, Method -> {"Canvas" -> None},ChartLegends -> {"F", "C", "B", "A"},Epilog -> {(*same order as names listed above*) Text[Style[ToString[Round[percentageSolvedByRubi, 0.01]] <> "%", Bold], Scaled[{.14, .6}]], Text[Style[ToString[Round[percentageSolvedByM, 0.01]] <> "%", Bold], Scaled[{.25, .6}]], Text[Style[ToString[Round[percentageSolvedByMaple, 0.01]] <> "%",Bold], Scaled[{.37, .6}]], Text[Style[ToString[Round[percentageSolvedByFricas, 0.01]] <> "%", Bold], Scaled[{.48, .6}]],Text[Style[ToString[Round[percentageSolvedByGiac, 0.01]] <> "%",Bold], Scaled[{.61, .6}]],Text[Style[ToString[Round[percentageSolvedBySympy, 0.01]] <> "%",Bold], Scaled[{.72, .6}]], Text[Style[ToString[Round[percentageSolvedByMaxima, 0.01]] <> "%", Bold], Scaled[{.84, .6}]]}];

i = Pane[ImageTrim[Rasterize[barchart],{{10, 200}, {1800, 1100}}]];

Grid[{{Text[Style["Antiderivative Grade distribution for each CAS", 20]]}, {Text[Style["Numbers shown on bars are total percentage solved for each CAS", 10]]}, {i}}, Frame -> All, Spacings -> {1, 1}, ItemSize -> Full]
```

[image: image2]

Comment: Thanks for the idea. But this makes the bars also smaller and little harder to see the numbers and the space is still too large compared to  V 12.

Comment: I added a second approach.